# Eclipse EGit Not able to clone repository

Tags: eclipse, gitlab

I am trying to clone a remote repository using Eclipse EGit and I keep getting the attached error.

[image]

Below is the configuration for "Clone Repository".

[Clone Repository Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYUBz.jpg)

I copied the repository URL from the Git repository directly and verified it is accessible.

Comment: What does the error log says? (metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/log)

Comment: I dont have the logs enabled by default, as I dont see the log generated under the mentioned folder. I will try to enable the logs and see what error I get.

Comment: OK. This is a good idea.

Comment: I found the problem. The git version on eclipse was out of date. Once I upgraded that, I was able to clone repository. Thank you very much